# Make image used as title of shinydashboard fits exactly in the title box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have put an image as title of my shiny dashboard and I have adjusted its size in order to fit in height and width but there is a small section in the left side which remains empty. How can I make it fit exactly in the box? (The blue part of the attached image remains empty)

[image]

```
# app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "gears",
  fixed = T,
  title = tags$a(href='http://mycompanyishere.com',
                                 tags$img(src='logo.png',height = "55px",width="232px"))
)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  dbHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$hr(),
    tabsetPanel(
      id ="tabA",
      type = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Front",icon = icon("accusoft")),
      tabPanel("Data", icon = icon("table")
      )
    )
  ),
  rightsidebar = rightSidebar()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to modify dashboard CSS (i.e. padding). One way would be to insert

```
 tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
```

inside  `dashboardBody()`

Then the output looks like this (I don't have your logo but from an image below, you can see that blue part is gone).

[image]

For more on how to style apps in Shiny see here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Comment: I'm glad to help.